# How to delete from my database in PHP/mysql?

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

Hi there I have many implementations of some php files. All of which have some errors. I will start off with an apology as this is my first question on here and I am certain that I will do this incorrectly as I see many first timers do. I will give as much info as possible and make it relevant to as many people as possible.

I have a database and am having trouble deleting from it. The database is simple. It includes resource_id name room description time_available and uer_id.

Although I expect it to output name description and resources_id it only outputs name and description and it will not let me delete name by resources_id.

How to delete from my database in PHP/mysql?

```
    This is my delete_resources.php
    {
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Delete a Record from MySQL Database</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <?php

    $db_host = "@@@@@@@";

    // Place the username for the MySQL database here

    $db_username = "@@@@@@@"; 

    // Place the password for the MySQL database here

    $db_pass = "@@@@@@@";

    // Place the name for the MySQL database here

    $db_name = "@@@@@@@";


    //
    $con = mysqli_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass","$db_name");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())

      {

      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();

      mysqli_close($con);

      }

     $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM resources");


     echo 'name' . "\t" . 'description' . "\t" . 'resources_id';
     echo "<br>";

     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
       echo $row['name'] . "\t" . $row['description'] . "\t" . $row['resources_id'];
       echo "<br>";
    }


    // Echoes: string

    echo gettype($array);

    //

    if(isset($_POST['delete']))
    {

      // Query to select an int column


        $resources_id = $_POST['resources_id'];

        $sql = "DELETE name From resources ".
               "WHERE resources_id = $resources_id" ;



    //mysql_select_db('b32_13993766_csc411');
    //$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
    if(! $result )
    {
      die('Could not delete data: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    else if( $result )
    {
        echo "Deleted data successfully\n";
    }

    //mysql_close($conn);
    }
    else
    {
    ?>
    <form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
    <table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
    <tr>
    <td width="100">Resource ID</td>
    <td><input name="resources_id" type="text" id="resources_id"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="100"> </td>
    <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="100"> </td>
    <td>
    <input name="delete" type="submit" id="delete" value="Delete">
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
//
}
```

Comment: You don't specify column names when executing DELETE queries: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html

Comment: @Mayank thanks for the tip, but anyone whose ever written a paper or been to school or college knows that google can be more of a time waster most times because of the overwhelming amount of random information that isn't specific or helpful enough. I used google AGAIN and found the most helpful to be stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are *not* **executing** that delete query. Should look like

```
 $recources_id=intval($resources_id);
 $sql = "DELETE FROM resources WHERE resources_id = $resources_id" ;
 $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);  // This is missing
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql_query="Delete from your_table_name where id ='".$your_id."'";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM resources WHERE resources_id = $resources_id" ;
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `$result` is not relevant at all with your delete query (it is referring to the $result above, not the one with the delete). Try changing to this and see if it works.

```
if(isset($_POST['delete']))
{

  // Query to select an int column


    $resources_id = $_POST['resources_id'];

    $sql = "DELETE name From resources ".
           "WHERE resources_id = $resources_id" ;

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql); //add this line        

//mysql_select_db('b32_13993766_csc411');
//$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $result )
{
  die('Could not delete data: ' . mysql_error());
}
else if( $result )
{
    echo "Deleted data successfully\n";
}

//mysql_close($conn);
}
```

Comment: Give connection to mysqli_query

Comment: there, my bad, been a long time since i havent used `mysqli query`

Comment: @railsbox why on earth should he use `mysql_query` here?

Comment: @railsbox, the guy use `mysqli_connect` to connect to database, besides, `mysql_query` is deprecated already

Comment: Please don't repeat text book security issues. Using user supplied data as is in sql queries is a really, really bad idea.

Comment: @user2002495 that didn't work. still getting "Could not delete data:"

Comment: change `mysql_error()` to `mysqli_error()` and see what the error is all about